# Link filtered Combobox Item to input

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, javafx-8

In my editable ComboBox which filters my suggestions due to input, I can fire `Button` events. The problem is, if I type one of the names of my items (like `action3`) in the editable field and click on the first suggestion (which also would be `action3`) which is the suitable item, it always fires the ButtonEvent with the first index `action1`, because it has the first index, but the first index is `action1`.

```
List<EventHandler<ActionEvent>> handlers = Arrays.asList(
            this::action1,
            this::action2,
            this::action3
            );
```

So how do I link like the action1 to my suggestion correct suggestion?

```
public void onEnter(ActionEvent event){
    int index = editableComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    if (index >= 0) {
         handlers.get(index).handle(event);
    }

}
```

**EDIT 1:**

My new initialize() Method looks like this:

```
protected void initialize() {
    new AutoCompleteBox<>(autoBox);     
    ObservableList<ActionEventHandler> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new ActionEventHandler("action1", this::action1),
            new ActionEventHandler("action2", this::action2,
            new ActionEventHandler("action3", this::action3)
    );
    autoBox.getItems().setAll(data);
    FilteredList<ActionEventHandler> filtered = new FilteredList<>(data);
    ComboBox<ActionEventHandler> autoBox = new ComboBox<>(filtered);
    autoBox.setOnAction(event -> {
        ActionEventHandler h = autoBox.getValue();
        if (h != null) {
            h.handle(event);
        }
    });
    autoBox.setEditable(true);
    autoBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<ActionEventHandler>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(ActionEventHandler object) {
            return object == null ? "" : object.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public ActionEventHandler fromString(String string) {
            if (string == null) {
                return null;
            }
            for (ActionEventHandler h : data) {
                if (string.equals(h.toString())) {
                    return h;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    });

    autoBox.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filtered.setPredicate(h -> h.toString().startsWith(newValue));
    });

}
```

And the custom `ComboBox` class:

```
public class AutoCompleteBox<T> implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

    private ComboBox comboBox;
    private StringBuilder sb;
    private ObservableList<T> data;
    private boolean moveCaretToPos = false;
    private int caretPos; 

    public AutoCompleteBox(final ComboBox comboBox) {
        this.comboBox = comboBox;
        sb = new StringBuilder();      
        data = comboBox.getItems();



        this.comboBox.setEditable(true);
        this.comboBox.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                comboBox.hide();
            }
        });
        this.comboBox.setOnKeyReleased(AutoCompleteBox.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
            caretPos = -1;
            moveCaret(comboBox.getEditor().getText().length());
            return;
        } else if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
            if(!comboBox.isShowing()) {
                comboBox.show();
            }
            caretPos = -1;
            moveCaret(comboBox.getEditor().getText().length());
            return;
        } else if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
            moveCaretToPos = true;
            caretPos = comboBox.getEditor().getCaretPosition();
        } else if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.DELETE) {
            moveCaretToPos = true;
            caretPos = comboBox.getEditor().getCaretPosition();
        }

        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT || event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT
                || event.isControlDown() || event.getCode() == KeyCode.HOME
                || event.getCode() == KeyCode.END || event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
            return;
        }

        ObservableList list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
            if(data.get(i).toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(
                    AutoCompleteBox.this.comboBox
                .getEditor().getText().toLowerCase())) {
                list.add(data.get(i));
            }
        }
        String t = comboBox.getEditor().getText();

        comboBox.setItems(list);
        comboBox.getEditor().setText(t);
        if(!moveCaretToPos) {
            caretPos = -1;
        }
        moveCaret(t.length());
        if(!list.isEmpty()) {
            comboBox.show();
        }
    }

    private void moveCaret(int textLength) {
        if(caretPos == -1) {
            comboBox.getEditor().positionCaret(textLength);
        } else {
            comboBox.getEditor().positionCaret(caretPos);
        }
        moveCaretToPos = false;
    }
}
```

I can't link the functions (like `action1` to the String `action1`) or what I believe more, I can't combine the custom class with my custom `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it seems to be best to use `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`s as items that return the strings for `toString`. Add a `converter` to convert the item to a non-`String` object.

```
public class ActionEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    private final EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler;
    private final String name;

    public ActionEventHandler(String name, EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        Objects.requireNonNull(eventHandler);
        this.name = name;
        this.eventHandler = eventHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        eventHandler.handle(event);
    }

}
```

```
ObservableList<ActionEventHandler> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new ActionEventHandler("action1", this::action1),
        new ActionEventHandler("action2", this::action2),
        new ActionEventHandler("action3", this::action3)
);
FilteredList<ActionEventHandler> filtered = new FilteredList<>(data);
ComboBox<ActionEventHandler> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(filtered);
comboBox.setOnAction(event -> {
    ActionEventHandler h = comboBox.getValue();
    if (h != null) {
        h.handle(event);
    }
});
comboBox.setEditable(true);
comboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<ActionEventHandler>() {

    @Override
    public String toString(ActionEventHandler object) {
        return object == null ? "" : object.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public ActionEventHandler fromString(String string) {
        if (string == null) {
            return null;
        }
        for (ActionEventHandler h : data) {
            if (string.equals(h.toString())) {
                return h;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

});
comboBox.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    filtered.setPredicate(h -> h.toString().startsWith(newValue));
});
```

---

**Edit**

The following code should work together with your `AutoCompleteBox` class.

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<ActionEventHandler> autoBox;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    autoBox.getItems().setAll(
            new ActionEventHandler("action1", this::action1),
            new ActionEventHandler("action2", this::action2),
            new ActionEventHandler("action3", this::action3));
    autoBox.setOnAction(event -> {
        ActionEventHandler h = autoBox.getValue();
        if (h != null) {
            h.handle(event);
        }
    });
    autoBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<ActionEventHandler>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(ActionEventHandler object) {
            return object == null ? "" : object.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public ActionEventHandler fromString(String string) {
            if (string == null) {
                return null;
            }
            for (ActionEventHandler h : autoBox.getItems()) {
                if (string.equals(h.toString())) {
                    return h;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    });
    new AutoCompleteBox<>(autoBox);
}
```

(I haven't checked the details of your `AutoCompleteBox` class though...)

Comment: I made a own ComboBox in a new class `AutoCompleteBox<>(autoBox);` which is already editable, can I add your lower code in my Controllers `initialize()` and just call `new AutoCompleteBox<>(autoBox);` afterwards? I'm getting an empty Dropdown list.

Comment: @Flippy remove the combobox creation from my lower code, add it to the `initialize()` method of the controller and use `comboBox.getItems().setAll(...)` instead of specifying the items list in the `ComboBox` constructor. (IDK if you have to modify my code with your custom `ComboBox` type...) And of course replace `comboBox` with the field name of the `ComboBox` you use.

Comment: I edit the code in my question above, right now I get the elements (action1 .. ) but I can't use the actions.

Comment: I do not see you adding the `ComboBox` to the scene somewhere... Furthermore you should probably not combine your filtering approach with mine.

Comment: I added the ComboBox in my Controller above with `@FXML ComboBox autoBox;` and I placed it in SceneBuilder (inside FXML from the Controller)

Comment: I have an error in line `for (ActionEventHandler h : data) {` because of data  `cannot resolved to variable`

Comment: But if I comment that if out, it works as I expect it should, thanks for your hard help, VERY BIG THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

try to get the string of the item and check for the string content. if its "action3" you call the event for action3. code:`(String) cbKategorieMain.getSelectedItem()` will get you the content of the combobox as string

Comment: I think more about updating the index number to the shown suggestions.